# pick a value from array

Tags: php, curl

i have a curl request which fetches response, response comes as plain text, i need to read a value from response.
i have used below method it works using ID, i want to use name of field rather than ID as sequence could change.

response received via CURL (PHP) is:

```
responseType=query&accountId=112233&responseCode=C2&responseMessage=Request+Accepted&transactionId=233112&transactionCode=&cycleCode=30764&cycleId=30764&terminalMessage=&requestId=r9e7e61fd-3321-4ezz-9e19-fea1773ed812
```

I am only interested in REQUEST ID VALUE

through JSON it comes as ID 9, but there is no guarantee that it will be at end and ID9, it depends on request.

if i assume ID9 all times, it could be wrong

Code im using is:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://127.0.0.1/api?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "requestType=query&userName=test-kal&accountId=112233&key=nt125hsndh54nb4nj&processingMode=queue&sequence=100&transactionIndustryType=ZZ&pageFormat=PT&returnURLPolicy=redirect&accountType=R&notifyURL=https%3A%2F%2Ftestdom.co.uk&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fmkc.co.uk");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
echo '<br><br>Json encoding:';
$res= explode('&', $result);
print_r($res);
echo '<br><br>Trying to read requestID now on new line:<br><br>';
//by calling ID
echo $res['9']; // this outputs field and value
//trying using field name
$json = json_decode($res, true);
echo $json['requestId']; //this doesnt work

?>
```

Comment: 'code' Code didnt show properly
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://127.0.0.1/api?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "requestType=query&userName=test-kal&accountId=112233&key=nt125hsndh54nb4nj&processingMode=queue&sequence=100&transactionIndustryType=ZZ&pageFormat=PT&returnURLPolicy=redirect&accountType=R&notifyURL=https%3A%2F%2Ftestdom.co.uk&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fmkc.co.uk");

Comment: $headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
echo '<br><br>Json encoding:';
$res= explode('&', $result);
print_r($res);
echo '<br><br>Trying to read requestID now on new line:<br><br>';
//by calling ID
echo $res['9']; // this outputs field and value
//trying using field name
$json = json_decode($res, true);
echo $json['requestId']; //this doesnt work

?>

Comment: This is a pure programming question. It is off-topic on Security SE.

Comment: used PARSE_STR function as below to resolve my issue; $params = array();
parse_str($response, $params);
$requestId = $params['requestId'];
echo $requestId; just if anyone else ever encounters same issue

Comment: You need to [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Format the code in your question properly as per [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) then it's clear, readable and complete. And please make sure you provide a [mre] of the issue. You talk about JSON but no JSON is shown as far as I can see. Also the thing you describe as the response from cURL looks more like a URL querystring than an API response...are you sure that's what you mean? Normally APIs return JSON or XML directly. See also [ask] and the [tour] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: And if you solved the issue, please add it below as an Answer so it can be searched and found by others (comments are not searchable). See also [answer] (and again the [tour], if you don't understand how the Q&A format works on Stackoverflow (and other Stack sites)).

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple matter of parsing the string with [parse_str](https://www.php.net/parse_str) into an array and you're good to go.

```php
$str = "responseType=query&accountId=112233&responseCode=C2&responseMessage=Request+Accepted&transactionId=233112&transactionCode=&cycleCode=30764&cycleId=30764&terminalMessage=&requestId=r9e7e61fd-3321-4ezz-9e19-fea1773ed812";

parse_str($str, $params);

echo $params["requestId"]; // r9e7e61fd-3321-4ezz-9e19-fea1773ed812
```

Now it'll no longer matter where each array key is located, as you can just call the key.